# mini log-in form does not log in

Tags: blocks, custom, login, form-key

I put a *mini-login* block in the `left` column of home. But when I am trying to log-in from there, it takes me to the *log-in* page with no errors.

In my search, I have seen that we should use a variable `form_key`, but I am not sure about where should I place it.

Here is my code i put in `\app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\customer.xml`

```
<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_mini_login" before="-" template="customer/form/mini.login.phtml"/>
     ...
</customer_logged_out>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form_key` should go in your `customer/form/mini.login.phtml` file.

```
<?php $formKey = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();?>
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo $formKey; ?>" />
```

Comment: where exactly i should put this code? i must replace certain code ? also i need to add the "form_key" on my block?

Comment: nvm i am a dork it should be placed inside the <form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post"> ..... </form> before the block-content.

Thx for the answer!